# object[value].innerHTML showing undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

```js
console.log('Welcome to flight Tracker API.js');

let mainDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
let Trow = document.querySelectorAll('.tablerow');
let Trow1 = document.getElementById('tablerow_id1');
let newDiv;

let datas = [
    ['14:01' ,'FRANKFRUIT','FR402','B02','ONTIME'],
    ['FRANKFURT' ,'Frankfruit','canada','russia','ukrain'],
    ['FRANKFURT' ,'Frankfruit','canada','russia','ukraine'],
    ['FRANKFURT' ,'Frankfruit','canada','russia','ukraine'],
    ['FRANKFURT' ,'Frankfruit','canada','russia','ukraine']
]

//td and div generator

for(i of datas[0]){
    //console.log(i);
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    //console.log(td);
    let charr = i.split("");
    let holderDiv = document.createElement('div');
    holderDiv.setAttribute('class','holderDiv');
    holderDiv.classList.add('.holderDiv');
    charr.forEach((e) => {
        newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('class','newDiv');
        let collections = document.querySelectorAll('.newDiv');
        newDiv.innerHTML = e;

        //console.log(collections[17].innerHTML);
        holderDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
        td.appendChild(holderDiv);
        Trow[0].appendChild(td);
    });
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: varela;
    src: url('Font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf');
}
body{
    background: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.596);
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
:root{
    --width:50.5rem;
    --mainwidth:2rem;
}
.main{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width: 53rem;
    height: 17rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: varela;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
}
.top_head{
    position: absolute;
    /*background: green;*/
    height: 3rem;
    width: 52rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.td1{
   position: relative;
   
}
.tableContainer{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 40rem;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
}
th{
    width: 90rem;
    text-align: left;
    /*background: yellow;*/
}
td{
    text-align: left;
    /*background: green;*/
}
td:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 4rem;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    padding-left: 3.4rem;
}
td:nth-child(4){
    padding-left: 4.75rem;
}
td:nth-child(5){
    padding-left: 5.45rem;
}
table{
    background: rgb(92, 86, 86);
    width: 52rem;
    height: 14rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.holderDiv{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background:rgb(65, 60, 60);
    width: fit-content;
    border: 3px solid rgb(65, 60, 60);
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
}
.newDiv{
    background: black;
    width: fit-content;
    animation: rotate .4s linear forwards;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.newDiv:nth-child(1){
    margin-left: 0;
}

@keyframes rotate{
    0%{
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    50%{
      transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flightTracker.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script defer src="flightTracker.js"></script>
    <div class="main">
        <span class="top_head">DEPARTURES</span>
        <div class="tableContainer"><table class="table" id="table_id">
            <thead class="head">
                <tr>
                    <th>TIME</th>
                    <th>DESTINATION</th>
                    <th>FLIGHT</th>
                    <th>GATE</th>
                    <th>REMARKS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody class="tableBody" id="tableBody_id">
            <tr class="tablerow" id="tablerow_id1"></tr>
            <tr class="tablerow" id="tablerow_id2"></tr>
            <tr class="tablerow" id="tablerow_id3"></tr>
            <tr class="tablerow" id="tablerow_id4"></tr>
            <tr class="tablerow" id="tablerow_id5"></tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to see the `innerHTML` of `collections[17]` and change its style but it's showing `undefined`. The collections are `HTMLcollections` of divs. Please someone help me sort it out. I tried many methods but all resulted in an `undefined` error. Please have a look at the snippet I have provided. The `collections[17]` are present in the code and I can select them but cannot change their style or see their `innerHLML`.

Comment: Please share more details, like the markup involved

Comment: ok I will share a JSfiddle file

Comment: No, add all the necessary code in question itself and not behind a link. See [ask]. You can [create a runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) within your question if you prefer.

Comment: it is showing undefined in console that means collections[17] is not present in collections array . collections[17] means you are trying to get the 18th element from the array which is not present . so it is printing undefined . you can check the length of the array like collections.length .

Comment: collections.length is showing 28 which means the 17th object is present in it. I have updated the code please have look.

Comment: In the code you are sharing you are adding `newDiv` elements dynamically, so depending on when you are checking the length of collections it may return undefined. For example, the first time you loop `charr.forEach`, the line `//console.log(collections[17].innerHTML);` would return undefined (if you uncomment it)

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out. I now use a if statement to check if length is 28 and then console .log it.Thanks for all your help.